# disambiguate Operator usage with example in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

What is the usage of disambiguate operator **::** in PIG. It is used in JOIN,FILTER,FLATTEN and so on. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not used in** `JOIN,FILTER,FLATTEN`.It is used to identify the fields in a relation **after** `JOIN, COGROUP, CROSS, or FLATTEN` operators.Click [Source](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#disambiguate) to see an example.

You use `JOIN, COGROUP, CROSS` operators on more than 1 relation,except for `FLATTEN`.This will result in a relation that is made of fields from more than 1 relation.In that case to identify the fields you will have to use the disambiguate operator.